# When to load data for RESTful URLs

Tags: rest, symfony, angularjs

This is my first time trying to use RESTful URL's, and I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around when information should be loaded from the database.

For reference, I am using Symfony2. I want to use AngularJS to load data using my RESTful URL's.

Let's say for example I want to load a list of someones favourite movies. When I send a GET request to /{username}/movies, should the response be an entire rendered HTML view, which includes the AngularJS app, and a list of the users favourite movies?

This seems very messy, and I'd rather have it return just a JSON response of a list of the users favourite movies; allowing me to call that reuse that URL in different parts of the website.

If I want the URL to return *just* a JSON response, should the process go like this:

1. User loads /{username}/movies/
2. Symfony2 Controller builds a page containing an AngularJS app, no movie data is currently loaded.
3. AngularJS then sends a GET request to a different URL (/{username}/restmovies/)?

This method seems cleaner to me, but I feel like having separate URL's for drawing the application, and loading the data is not the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, separation of concerns. You can have your urls, where you load the normal html site for the user, and under `/api` you have all the REST stuff.

Read this arcticle, its very helpful: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/